# Tkinter: Code stops and window doesn't show up

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a very basic interface on Python with Tkinter, that displays two input boxes and a button to login. I try to do it by creating different frames and change the frame when the user is logged. It was working nearly fine but then the code started to execute itself not entirely sometimes and entirely but without the Tkinter window. I looked into it and saw nothing shocking but I am not an expert so I am looking for help.
This is the code to run my class that implement Tkinter window:

```
print 1
app = Skeleton("HomePage")
print 2
app.mainloop()
print 3
```

The skeleton Class that implement the Tkinter window:

```
class Skeleton(Tk):
def __init__(self, f,*args, **kwags):
    Tk.__init__(self,*args, **kwags)
    self.title(f)
    container = Frame(self, width=512, height=512)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   
    self.frames = {}
    frameName = {"home","upload","retrieve","deconnected"}
    self.frames["HomePage"] = HomePage(parent= container, controller=self)
    self.frames["HomePage"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    print 321
    self.show_frame("HomePage")

def show_frame(self, page_name):
    '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
    print "Je vais te montrer mon frame" 
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.tkraise()
```

And the code of the Home Page frame:

```
class HomePage(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.controller = controller
    #print ("Construction de la page dáccueil")
    #LABEL
    self.username = Label(self, text="Username:")
    self.username.grid(row =0,column =0)
    self.username.pack()

    #ENTRY
    self.username_txb = Entry( self)
    self.username_txb.focus_set() 
    self.username_txb.grid(row =0,column =1)
    self.username_txb.pack(side=LEFT)

    #LABEL
    self.pass_lbl = Label(self, text="Password:")
    self.pass_lbl.grid(row =0,column =2)

    #ENTRY 
    self.password_txb = Entry( self, text="Password", show = "*")
    self.password_txb.grid(row =0,column =3)
    self.password_txb.pack(side=LEFT)

    #LOGIN BUTTON
    self.login_btn = Button(self, text="Login", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("UploadPage"))
    self.login_btn.grid(row =0,column =4)
    self.login_btn.pack(side=LEFT)


    self.info_pane = PanedWindow()
    self.info_pane.grid(row =1,column =0)
    self.info_pane.pack(fill="none", expand=True, side=BOTTOM)
    self.info_lbl = Label(self, text="More information about access:", fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
    self.contact_lbl = Label(self, text="Contact us", fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
    self.contact_lbl.grid(row =2,column =0)
    self.contact_lbl.pack()
    self.contact_lbl.bind("<Button-1>", self.callback)
    print ("123Construction de la page dáccueil")
    #self.parent.update()


def callback(self, event):
    pass 

def connect(self,controller ):
    login = self.username_txb.get()
    pwd = self.password_txb.get()
    if(login == "a" and pwd == "a"):
        print "Valid account"  
        self.controller.show_frame("UploadPage")
        #UploadPage frame is implemented
```

The output everytime I execute the code is as following:

> 1 
>   123Construction de la page dáccueil

Thank you in advance for the help. Hope this will help other people.

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your problem, but your code as posted is not indented correctly. The member functions are not indented within the class declarations.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You are also trying to use `grid()` and `pack()` on the same widgets at the same time. This will not work. You cannot mix the 2 in the same frame/window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets address your use of `pack()` and `grid()`.
Due to how tkinter is set up you cannot use both `pack()` and `grid()` on the same widget in a frame or window at one time.

You may use for example `pack()` to pack the main frame and `grid()` on the widgets inside that frame but you cannot use both in side the frame.

If one of your issues is where each widget is located and if it is expanding with the window you can manage all that inside of `grid()` so we can just use `grid()` here as its what I prefer when writing up a GUI.

Next we need to look at your call to `show_frame` as you are attempting to show a frame that does not exist in `self.frames` in the code you have presented us.

I have created a new class so your program can be tested with this line of code:
`self.controller.show_frame("UploadPage")`

The new class just makes a basic frame with a label in it showing that the frame does rise properly with `tkrise()`.

I did some general clean up as your `show_frame` method was taking unnecessary steps to raise the frame, your method of importing tkinter is not the best option and some other quality corrections.

Instead of using:

```
frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.tkraise()
```

We can simplify this method with just one line like this:

```
self.frames[page_name].tkraise()
```

I have also changed how you are importing tkinter as importing with * can sometimes cause problems if you inadvertently override build in methods. The best option is to import tkinter like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Take a look at the below code and let me know if you have any questions. It should provide the info you need to allow the `HomePage` frame and `UploadPage` frame to work as intended.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Skeleton(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, f,*args, **kwags):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args, **kwags)
        self.title(f)
        self.container = tk.Frame(self, width=512, height=512)
        self.container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 

        self.frames = {}
        self.frames["HomePage"] = HomePage(parent=self.container, controller=self)
        self.frames["HomePage"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames["UploadPage"] = UploadPage(parent=self.container)
        self.frames["UploadPage"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("HomePage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        self.frames[page_name].tkraise()

class HomePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller

        self.username = tk.Label(self, text="Username:")
        self.username.grid(row =0,column =0)
        self.username_txb = tk.Entry(self)
        self.username_txb.focus_set() 
        self.username_txb.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.pass_lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Password:")
        self.pass_lbl.grid(row =0,column =2)
        self.password_txb = tk.Entry(self, text="Password", show="*")
        self.password_txb.grid(row =0,column =3)

        self.login_btn = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=self.connect)
        self.login_btn.grid(row=0, column=4)

        self.info_pane = tk.PanedWindow()
        self.info_pane.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.info_lbl = tk.Label(self, text="More information about access:", fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
        self.contact_lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Contact us", fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
        self.contact_lbl.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.contact_lbl.bind("<Button-1>", self.callback)

    def callback(self, event):
        pass 
        # webbrowser.open_new("https://www.tno.nl/nl/")
        # I do not have the import for this webbrowser so I disabled it for testing.    

    def connect(self):
        login = self.username_txb.get()
        pwd = self.password_txb.get()
        if(login == "a" and pwd == "a"):
            self.controller.show_frame("UploadPage")

class UploadPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text="This upload frame is a test to see if your code is working").grid(row=0, column=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Skeleton("HomePage")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me to understand better how to use the Tkinter GUI(that I used in a really bad way 4years ago). I adapted my code to yours, the Tk window didn't open but when I just copied your code it worked. I will start on your code base to make a proper code.